# An inequality regarding operator concave function

Tags: matrix-analysis, convex-analysis, traces, hermitian, trace-formula

[Crossposted from math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235831/proving-an-inequality-for-operators)

> Let $\mathbb P_n$ be the space of all $n \times n$ self-adjoint positive definite matrices. Consider the function $\varphi: \mathbb P_n \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$\varphi (A) = -\text {tr}\ (A \log A).$$ Show that for all $t \in (0,1)$ $$\varphi ((1 - t) A + t B) \leq (1 - t) \varphi (A) + t \varphi (B) - \eta (t,1-t)$$ where $\eta (t,1 - t) = t \log (t) + (1 - t) \log (1 - t).$

I know that $\varphi$ is operator concave. But I don't have any idea as to how to bound $\varphi$ from above. Could anyone please give me some hint?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is a website for professional mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. Homework problems are off-topic here.

Comment: @Nik Weaver this is not a homework problem. I have found it in the exercise of my book in matrix analysis. Could you please give me some hint? I have also asked it in MSE but couldn't get any response from anybody. So I thought that it could very well be related to research problem in matrix analysis. That's why I have posted it here. Thanks.